# How are HTTP requests handled in Java Web Services?

Tags: java, web-services, servlets

I am new to web services and am going through the book *Java Webservices* by Martin Kalin. I have gone through the initial basic concept of it and have a question:

Say `producer` sends the HTTP request (containing SOAP Message envelope) to a Java web service (`consumer`). Is the request internally handled by Servlet which extracts the SOAP message and convert it to corresponding Java domain object and then service implementation bean is called?

This question generic irrespective of any off the shelf framework like Metro and Axis. Just consider below code

```
 Endpoint.publish("webserviceURL", new CustomerServiceImpl())
```

Now if consumer sends the request to `webserviceURL`, will it be handled by Servlet always at the entry point or handled in some other way? (As this is how web request is handled in any web application)

Comment: This is the typical "create a simple Java 6 (or later) application containing a web service" approach.  This is a tiny web server enclosed in the JAX-WS web service stack implementation coming with Java.  Another approach is needed if you need to deploy your code to an application server like Glassfish, JBoss or WebLogic.

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen whether i publish my webservice thru "tiny web server enclosed in the JAX-WS web service stack implementation coming with Java" or some other framework like jersery etc, http web service request will also be  handled by servlets only at consumer entry point. Is it right?

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Requests are handled by Something That Can Handle HTTP Requests, period.

It's convenient to use servlets or filters because the plumbing has already been written for you in the form of the servlet/application container, but this isn't a requirement. For example, a service running on Netty wouldn't need to follow the servlet spec. (Although IIRC there's a layer to allow Netty to call servlets directly.)

As long as both the client and server are talking HTTP the underlying implementation doesn't matter, and doesn't need to be servlets–it just needs to talk HTTP.

Comment: But as per myunderstanding, http requests can only be handled by servlets only in case of java container. But you are saying Netty is an example where http requests are not handled by servlet but in some other way. Right?

Comment: @emilly HTTP requests can be handled by anything that can handle an HTTP request. What is HTTP? A textual request/response mechanism. Text comes in over a socket, gets parsed, and a response is sent back. As long as whatever is reading from the socket can correctly handle HTTP it doesn't make any difference *what* is handling that request. Netty handles HTTP requests without servlets. If you could type faster than the client timeout you could answer it manually.

Comment: Thanks Dave. If you can provide your insight s on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16380657/some-basic-questions-about-webservice , that would really be helpful.

Answer (score 5):

A Servlet is a Java class that can receive a HTTP request and send a response back, right?

That being said, you could (if you *really really* wanted), code a full-blown web service using only Servlets (using its methods `doGet()` and `doPost()`).

You'd, for instance, get the HTTP request, byte by byte, make it into a `String`, parse it into a XML file and then interpret it as a SOAP Envelope (let's call this "**plumbing work**"), and only then would begin processing the *actual* request (what you really wanted in the first place).

After done processing the *actual* request, you'd have to do some **more** plumbing work to convert the objects back into XML, and SOAP Envelopes (and don't forget about the hassle of handling eventual faults/exceptions).

You ask:

> *Is the request internally handled by servlet which extracts the soap message and convert it to corresponding java domain object (...)*

The answer is **no**. The Servlets do nothing other than receiving the bytes and let you manipulate them in a Java method (e.g. `doGet()` or `doPost()`). You could do that manually, but the conversion of the data into domain objects is usually done by a *Web Service framework*.

> *Now if consumer sends the request to webservice URL, will it be handled by servlet always at the entry point or handled in some other way?*

The first one. It will always be handled by Servlets at the entry point. But you may ask:

> **Well, what is the point of a Web Service API like JAX-RS, Spring-WS or JAX-RS, then?**

All Java's famous web services APIs are built ***on top*** of the Servlet API.

The Servlets do are the first to handle the request, but this "handling" made is very  little: as I said, they only get the HTTP request bits and let you work with them as a Java method.

After that, the WS frameworks can do for you a bunch of other ***plumbing work***. For instance, they can get the HTTP POST request and do all the `Bytes<->XML<->SOAP Envelope<->Objects` conversion to you in a transparent way. They'll also help you defining standard Fault envelopes, generating WSDL files automatically, and everything else.

## Bottom line:

You can do all that yourself using only Servlets, but with a Web Service framework, you won't have to worry about all the **plumbing work** needed, and can go just about creating methods to handle the *actual* requests.

## Edit:

Just to make it clear: Servlets **aren't** by any chance the **only** way to handle HTTP requests with Java.

They are, though, the somewhat *standard* way of doing it in Java EE, as they are one of the [most **stable and undisputed** of the Java EE APIs](http://blog.codecentric.de/en/2011/03/java-ee-vs-spring-or-what-is-a-standard/), but there are other ways, of course - there always are.

What I said is the **most famous frameworks** are built on top of the Servlet API, just to point a few:

- JAX-RS:

  - Metro
  - Axis
  - Axis2
  - CXF
  - JBossWS
- JAX-RS:

  - Jersey,
  - RESTeasy;
  - CXF,
  - Restlet (the name says it all...)
- Others:

  - Spring-WS,
  - Spring MVC.

And this is, as I said, just to point a few.

Comment: You wouldn't even need servlets, for example, [RestExpress](https://github.com/RestExpress/RestExpress). Servlets are just a way of handling HTTP requests, but aren't the only way--HTTP is just a protocall.

Comment: I never said said Servlets are the only way. The OP cited Metro, Axis and Servlets, the answer was about it. Of course HTTP is just a protocol. I edited the answer to make it clearer.

Comment: I guess I was thrown off by "It will always be handled by Servlets at the entry point," and OP specifically said irrespective of framework.

Comment: Since we are talking about JavaEE/Servlet/Metro/Axis/OtherFwAlike context, Servlets do always handle it. But if one wanted exceptions, just to be technical about it, didn't have to go that far off. `javax.xml.ws.Endpoint` itself runs a HTTP server that is *not* a servlet container. Still, those fws are built on top of the Servlet API and their proper use as such will always have the entry point handled by it.

Answer (score 0):

All the web services work on top of servlets only be it SOAP or REST. Depending on which web service framework you use the servlet mapping will be configured such as jersey, resteasy etc.